# Simple binomial distribution inequality

Tags: probability

Is there a quick and simple way to prove the following inequality?

For $p < \frac{1}{2}$ , $\Pr(\text{Bin}(2n,p) \geq n) \geq \Pr(\text{Bin}(2n+2,p) \geq n+1)$